# Change Textview text in Dialog from Main Activity after ringtone selection dialog

Tags: java, android

Been at this for a while. Frustrating! Cannot think of or find a solution. I'm a nube to Java and Android which might explain my ignorance.

In the code below I would like to assign the ringtone that was selected to the Textview **ringtoneDisplay** - The main problem as I understand it is that the Textview is inside the dialog -  which cannot be changed from the Main Activity. How do you change the Textview in the dialog from the the Main Activity?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // When a configuration button is clicked that shows a dialog
    public void confClicked(View v) { 

        // Define and create a dialog to display
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog); 
            dialog.show();

            // Dialog has a button to change ringtone
            Button changeRing = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.changeRing);

            final TextView ringtoneDisplay = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ringtone_textview);

        changeRing.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Bring up ringtone change dialog
            Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select Tone");
            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, (Uri) null);
            MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(intent, 5);
            }
        });

    }

    // Fired after ringtone was selected 

    protected void onActivityResult (final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent intent)
     {

         if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 5)
             {
              Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);

              if (uri != null)
              {
                  **// --> This below won't work.. 
                  // --> declaring ringtoneDisplay outside confClicked creates a runtime error.
                  // --> How do you go about updating ringtoneDisplay to display the ringtone that was chosen

                  ringtoneDisplay.settext(RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, uri).getTitle(this));** 
              }


          }            

      }  


}
```

Answer (score 0):

First don´t use `Dialog`, as you can read from Android [documentation:](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

> The Dialog class is the base class for dialogs, but you should avoid instantiating Dialog directly. Instead, use one of the subclasses

This is what i suggest:
Create a method used to show Dialog

```
private void displayDialog(String ringtone)
```

From `confClicked(View v)` call it.
After `MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(intent, 5);` dismiss the dialog
In `OnActivityResult` call again `displayDialog` passing to it the ringtone selected.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

If I understand you correctly then what you're saying is that I must close the dialog and load it again. There is a lot of other things going on in the dialog that I did'nt include in the code here. Closing and openeing the Dialog again is going to cause issues... The ideal situation is where I can just update the Textview to indicate the ringtone selected.

Comment: As far as I know is not possible. May instead use another activity than Dialog

Comment: The purpose of a dialog is to ask or report something. If you want to deal with something is better to use an activity

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I figured that it's not possible .. after a day of head scratching and scouring the web and coming up with nothing. So I think I agree that it will in all likelyhood probably not be possible with the Dialog.